# webview определенного элемента

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! В своем проекте я использую `jsoup` чтобы парсить `html`. Но это все не очень красиво выглядит. Возможно ли спарсить определенный элемент сайта через `webview`? Чтобы он подгружал полностью блок со стилями и картинкой? Или есть какой-то другой вариант? Спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне jsoup лучший инструмент для парсинга. Но если вы хотите достать html через webview, то вам нужно будет сделать мост между js и webview и получать html под запросом js  [пример на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19519373/7540461)